# Is there any required number of years of experience before getting TVL-14 in Germany?"

Tags: postdocs, germany, salary

After completing my master's degree, I have work experience of 28 months with TVL-13, and I will finish my PhD soon. I got an offer from a new chair. Currently, there are one professor and me(as a postdoc), so there will be more responsibility for teaching and supervision.

Before my master's degree, I also have experience of 1.5 years in the Industry.

Do I qualify for the TVL-14 pay grade?

Comment: It depends on your responsibilities and tasks in the new job more than on your previous experience if you could be eligible for E14. This is something you should discuss with your new employer who will have to write a *Tätigkeitsbeschreibung* (job description). This description is important and should reflect your actual tasks.

Comment: Also relevant, if not duplicate: [If hired at TV-L 13, can you negotiate a promotion to TV-L 15?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/186955/7734)

Comment: The Gruppe depends on the job requirements and on the available funding. You will have to ask the professor if TV-L E14 is possible. In any case, 28 months does not seem like much: most doctoral students have more when they finish.

Comment: @wimi, okay thank you for giving an overview

Comment: You had 28 months full-time experience E13 after your master's? What about the PhD?

Comment: @user151413 I will be finishing soon

Comment: I see. The sentence is ambiguous, it could also have been read as "upon completing my master, I have 28 months E13 experience". What you mean is: After your master you did your PhD, in which you had 28 months of E13. I see.

Comment: @user151413 I have rephrased the line, thanks

Answer (score 9):

There is no "number of years" requirement for getting payscale E14.

E14 is distinguished from E13 by a different job profile (such as more responsibilities and more challenging duties, which potentially require certain education or experience).

Overall, regular postdocs are hired in E13 in most cases and places, but E14 is also possible.